# Better pattern to handle DAO creation for POJO using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, design-patterns, ormlite

I'm working on an Android App that use **SQLCipher**, **ORMLite for Android** to handle to POJO storing with SQLite and **Jackson** for parsing.

I'm wondering if there would be a better pattern that the one i'm using (Recommended by [stayforit](http://www.stayforit.com))  to get the DAO corresponding to the Entity class given. I have over 30 Entity class and I keep adding some over the time and each time, I have to create a DAO class that looks exactly the same as the previous one. How could I generalize using a generic class?

Here is my DbManager class:

```
public class DbManager {
    private static DbManager instance;
    private CipherDbHelper dbHelper;
    private SecureSharedPreferences settings;

    private DbManager() {

    }

    private DbManager(Context context, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
        dbHelper = new CipherDbHelper(context, password);
    }

    public static void init(Context context, String password) {
        instance = new DbManager(context, password);
    }

    public static DbManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            Log.e("DbManager", "DbManager is null");
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public <D extends Dao<T, String>, T> D getDAO(Class<T> clz) throws SQLException {
        return dbHelper.getDao(clz);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a recurrent DAO class I need to generate each time I add a POJO entity to my project:

```
public class CategoriesDAO extends BaseDAO<EntityCategories> {
    private static CategoriesDAO instance;

    private CategoriesDAO() {
    }

    public synchronized static CategoriesDAO getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CategoriesDAO();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Dao<EntityCategories, String> getDAO() throws SQLException, java.sql.SQLException {
        return DbManager.getInstance().getDAO(EntityCategories.class);
    }
}
```

Here is how I use it in an Activity:

```
CategoriesDAO.getInstance().addOrUpdate(categories);
```

Comment: You could look into Cupboard as an alternative to ORMLite. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Easier-SQL-with-Cupboard

Comment: @cricket_007 It looks nice, but I need to be able to handle nested object (single to many relation) which that specific ORM doesn't support...

Comment: Check out [JDXA ORM](http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html). JDXA can handle nested objects and does not require you to create a DAO class for every entity (model) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the instances of your POJO daos in a map either inside your BaseDao itself or in a subclass and then use an unchecked cast to extract it out.

```
public class GenericDao<T> extends BaseDao<T>  {

  private static class InstanceHolder {
      static final Map<Class<?>, GenericDao<?>> INSTANCES = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public static synchronized <T> GenericDao<T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
      GenericDao<T> dao = (GenericDao<T>)InstanceHolder.INSTANCES.get(clazz);
      if (dao == null) {
        dao = new GenericDao<T>();
        InstanceHolder.INSTANCES.put(clazz, dao);
      }
      return dao;
  }

  private GenericDao() {
  }
}
```

and then

```
    GenericDao<EntityCategories> foo = GenericDao.getInstance(EntityCategories.class);
    foo.addOrUpdate(....);
```

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you! Is unchecked cast a bad practice or should i not bother about it?

Comment: @Jaythaking in general, unchecked casts could be dangerous..but in this particular use case, you know that what you are putting into that map is basically just a key value pair containing your class name along with the instance.. so you know what you will get back.

Answer (score 3):

That's the way I like to use Ormlite DAO's:

CRUDOperator:

```
public interface CRUDOperator<T> {

    void create(T obj);

    void update(T obj);

    void delete(T obj);
}
```

Repo:

```
public interface Repo<T> extends CRUDOperator<T>{

    Optional<T> queryForId(Integer id);
    ObservableList<T> queryForAll();
    ...
}
```

OrmliteRepo:

```
public class OrmliteRepo<T> implements Repo<T> {

    protected Dao<T, Integer>          dao;

    protected OrmliteRepo(Dao<T, Integer> dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public ObservableList<T> queryForAll() throws SQLException {
        List<T> results =  dao.queryForAll();
        return Validators.isNullOrEmpty(results) ? FXCollections.observableArrayList() : FXCollections.observableArrayList(results);
    }

    public Optional<T> queryForId(Integer id) throws SQLException {
        T result = dao.queryForId(id);
        return Optional.ofNullable(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(T obj) throws SQLException {
            dao.create(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T obj) throws SQLException {
            dao.update(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T obj) throws SQLException {
            dao.delete(obj);
    }
}
```

YourRepo:

```
public class YourRepo extends OrmliteRepo<YourModel> {

    public YourRepo(Dao<YourModel, Integer> dao) {
        super(dao);
    }
}
```

RepoService:

```
public interface RepoService {
    <T> Repo<T> get(Class<T> dataClass);
}
```

BaseRepoService:

```
public class BaseRepoService implements RepoService {

    private RepoFactory            repoFactory;
    private Map<Class<?>, Repo<?>> repoCache;

    public BaseRepoService(RepoFactory repoFactory) {
        this.repoFactory = repoFactory;
        repoCache = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Repo<T> get(Class<T> dataClass) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Repo<T> repo =  (Repo<T>) repoCache.get(dataClass);

        if (repo == null) {
            repo = createRepo(dataClass);
            repoCache.put(dataClass, repo);
        }
        return repo;
    }

    private <T> Repo<T> createRepo(Class<T> dataClass) {
        return repoFactory.createRepo(dataClass);
    }
}
```

RepoFactory:

```
public interface RepoFactory {
    public <T> Repo<T> createRepo(Class<T> dataClass);
}
```

OrmliteRepoFactory:

```
public class OrmliteRepoFactory implements RepoFactory {

    private DbAccess                                      dbAccess;
    private final Map<Class<?>, Supplier<OrmliteRepo<?>>> suppliers;

    public OrmliteRepoFactory(DbAccess dbAccess) {
        this.dbAccess = dbAccess;

        suppliers = new HashMap<>();
        suppliers.put(YourModel.class, () -> new YourRepo(getDao(YourModel.class)));
    }

    private <T> Dao<T, Integer> getDao(Class<T> modelClass) {
        return dbAccess.getDaoImplementation(modelClass);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> OrmliteRepo<T> createRepo(Class<T> dataClass) {
        return (OrmliteRepo<T>) suppliers.get(dataClass).get();
    }
}
```

DbAccess:

```
public interface DbAccess {
     <T, R> R getDaoImplemantation(Class<T> dataClass);
}
```

OrmliteDbAccess:

```
public class OrmliteDbAccess implements DbAccess{

@Override
public <T, R> R getDaoImplementation(Class<T> objectClass) {
    R dao = null;

    try {
        dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, objectClass);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getting dao for class {}; {}", objectClass, e);
    }
    return dao;
}
```

}

Now all you need to do is add the suppliers for your repos to the repoFactory and make YourRepo.class extend OrmliteRepo.class. If I need some additional behaviour for a specific repo, I put it in that repo implementation.

When you have an instance of RepoService:

```
RepoService repoService = new BaseRepoService(ormliteRepoFactory);
```

you can access your repo like this:

```
Repo<YourModel> repo = repoService.get(YourModel.class);
```

Comment: It look interesting but a little overkill for my initial goal which was to simplify and shorten the codes

Comment: I'm not always convinced about the use of complex pattern when it comes to simple problems...but maybe your right and that allows modularity in case I wanted to swap to another library than ORMLite...

Comment: You are absolutely right Jaythaking. For your usecase it's overkill. But regarding the general nature of your question, I thought the pattern could be useful. (I'm using it on a Gluon multiplatform project hence the use of the interfaces)