# How to refactor helper methods with generics and foreign classes? (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, refactoring, ormlite

I'm building an Android app and using ORMLite for SQLite operations and want to create helper class for database handling. I have faced the problem of big code duplicates, but can't figure out how to refactor them.
Please advise if you have any thoughts about it.
I feel that this issue because of lack some basic knowledge, so if you can send me an advice, about which topic should i learn deeper, it will be awesome!

Here is the code blocks needs in refactoring:

```
public static BigGoal createBigGoalRecord(String title,
                                          String description,
                                          Dao<BigGoal, Integer> dao) throws SQLException {
    BigGoal bigGoal = new BigGoal(title, description);
    dao.create(bigGoal);
    assignBigGoalEmptyCollection(bigGoal, dao);
    return bigGoal;
}

public static SubGoal createSubGoalRecord(String title, String description,
                                          ObjectiveType type,
                                          Dao<SubGoal, Integer> dao,
                                          BigGoal bigGoal) throws SQLException {
    SubGoal subGoal = bigGoal.createSubGoal(title, description, type);
    dao.create(subGoal);
    assignSubGoalEmptyCollection(subGoal, dao);
    bigGoal.getSubGoals().add(subGoal);
    return subGoal;
}

public static List<BigGoal> getBigGoalList (Dao<BigGoal, Integer> dao) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<BigGoal> bigGoalList = new ArrayList<>();
    CloseableIterator<BigGoal> iterator = dao.closeableIterator();
    try {
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            BigGoal goal = iterator.next();
            bigGoalList.add(goal);
        }
    } finally {
        iterator.close();
    }

    return bigGoalList;
}

public static List<SubGoal> getSubGoalList (Dao<SubGoal, Integer> dao) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<SubGoal> subGoalList = new ArrayList<>();
    CloseableIterator<SubGoal> iterator = dao.closeableIterator();
    try {
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            SubGoal goal = iterator.next();
            subGoalList.add(goal);
        }
    } finally {
        iterator.close();
    }

    return subGoalList;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506936/better-pattern-to-handle-dao-creation-for-pojo-using-sqlite/36511610#36511610). It provides some basic ideas

Comment: Thank you! That's help me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle website has an entire section on Java generics here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

As an example, for your methods that return a list of an entity (e.g. `getBigGoalList()`), you could replace all of them with this one:

```
public static <T> List<T> getEntityList(Dao<T, Integer> dao) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    CloseableIterator<T> iterator = dao.closeableIterator();
    try {
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            T item = iterator.next();
            list.add(item);
        }
    } finally {
        iterator.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

I don't know enough about ORMLite to tell you if the same kind of refactoring would work for the methods that create and save an entity in your database. You might be better off having those methods take an instance of the entity as a parameter instead of taking all the arguments used to construct the entity, i,e:

```
createBigGoalRecord(BigGoal item, Dao<BigGoal, Integer> dao)
```

instead of

```
createBigGoalRecord(String title, String description, Dao<BigGoal, Integer> dao)
```

Otherwise I don't see an easy way to consolidate them into one method since they seem to need different arguments.

Comment: That's exactly, what i'm looking for! Thank you very much!